# How I can fix key Error in OrdinalEncoder?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, preprocessor, keyerror, encoder

[image]
hello guys. Hi guys. As you can see in the picture, when I tried to use the target column, I encountered a key error. I tried different ways but it did not work. When I type:
`y= train['Level']` or `y= train[['Level']]`
or
`print (Train['Level'])`
or
`enc = OrdinalEncoder() enc.fit(Train['Level'])`

and any other things about Level column this Error occured. how I can fix it? please help me "|
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NBPxN.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: so you mean that `Train['Level']` exists when you print it? Also please provide more details for example arent you trying to fit it with categories and transform on `Train['Level']`? At least show us what `Train` Looks like

Comment: it sounds like your `Train` does not contain `Level` column/key

Comment: @DemetreDzmanashvili Thank for your attention. I add train tabel in other picture

Comment: @Panah can you try `print(Train['Level']` and if an error still occurs try `print(Train.columns)` and show us the results. Thanks

Comment: @Ach113
no it's contain. I added other picture

Comment: @DemetreDzmanashvili I try that but still I got Error. this is result of `print(Train.columns)` :Index(['STG', 'SCG', 'STR', 'LPR', 'PEG', ' Level'], dtype='object')

Comment: @Panah as you can see `' Level'` contains space. now try `enc.fit(Train[' Level'])` and it will work but I suggest you fixing that name problem in the excel file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When there is `KeyError` in dataframe you should always check for the columns by `Train.columns` because sometimes it may contain spaces or other characters that can not be seen by the eye so it would be good if you always checked for that.

I also want to add suggestions to your code, because you are trying to encode the target variable why don't use `LabelEncoder` instead of `OrdinalEncoder`?

the input for `LabelEncoder` is `(n_samples,)` that seems the case for you and the input for `OrdinalEncoder` is `(n_samples, n_features)`. So I think you should use the first one.

Good Luck